# payment gateway in MVC .net project

Tags: payment-gateway

I wanted to create one shopping sites where user can do online payment through net banking,credit card and debit card.

For this application I am going to use MVC and JQuery. Now I just wanted to know about the payment gateway part.

1)Like how it will integrate with my code.

2)Do I need to use any third party controls for it and which is the best third party tool for this integration which is more secured.

3)How much they charge.

4)Is this amount will be payable my client or by me.

If any body done this kind of project please let me know the information.

Thanks,
Kapil.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to have payment gateway, there are lot of gateway provider but for their service you need to pay.
2)You must consume the payment gateway in your mvc code, no third party tools needed
3)Charge depends on the provider, but all the vendor charge alomost equally.
4)Amount will be payable by client, they will have contract agreed upon each other to seettle the charge.